# How can I speed up the rendering of an image on my page?

Tags: html, image

I am creating a site where the user can post their advertisement and the user  can upload a photo... I am posting the four latest ads pics in the top of my site... so everytime I navigate through my site those latest 4 ads pics will be displayed but the problem is it renders too long.. makes my site slowdown...

how can I optimize it? I need advice guys..

and btw, I'm saving those images in my database as blob.. and selecting the 4 latest ads in my database.

```
<?php if($latest_upload_count > 0){ ?>
<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
        <?php while($get_lastest_pics = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_5_latest_ads_query_string_execute)){ ?>
            <div class = "col-xs-3">
                <img img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($get_lastest_pics['img']); ?>"  style = "height: 180px; width: 270px;"  class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" >     
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

I tried omitting that and my site runs faster...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save your images as files and only save paths to them in the database. Then generate thumbnails of smaller size to display them on the homepage (e.g. with ability to zoom-in those images by clicking on them) or just scale-down and optimize those images. You can save paths to thumbnails in the database too, or you can generate them on-fly (using some prefixes/subfixes in file names for different sizes).

Use some of well-known PHP libraries for images manipulations (like [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) or similar).

Comment: oh okay... thank you for the advice.. btw, I save the image file in a folder and call it through a name?

Comment: You can save uploaded file in the temporary folder, process it (generate some thumbnails with different sizes, scale down the original one), save results in the publicly accessable folder and save paths of these results in the database to output them in your script.

Answer (score -1):

How about your code it self :
How about you write it like this :

```
if($latest_upload_count > 0){
    echo "<div class = 'collapse navbar-collapse'><div class = 'container'><div class = 'row'>";
    while($get_lastest_pics = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_5_latest_ads_query_string_execute)){
        echo "<div class = 'col-xs-3'>
            <img img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($get_lastest_pics['img'])."'  style = 'height: 180px; width: 270px;'  class='img-responsive img-thumbnail' alt='Cinque Terre' >     
        </div>";
    }
    echo "</div></div><br /></div>";
}
```

Comment: what is the difference? does it render faster if I do that?

Comment: you can try it out and then try some @vitalikaz image manipulations he mentioned. :)

Comment: the additional time involved in dumping files from db and using files that are too large will out swamp any microsecond improvment by not switching between html and php a suggestion which makes his code much harder to read and 100% unnecessary.  Beware premature optimisation.

Comment: Hmm, you're right about `by not switching between html and php a suggestion`. Thanks, for make me realize... :)